# I was working on my application but suddenly i got table does not exist in all my tables

Tags: mysql, localhost

Hey guy i was working on my app but suddenly i got an error says table does not exist in engine. 
When i went to see in my database i found out that all my tables are not working for w/e reason but as you can see (in the picture below) it says it does exist, i already checked if i have ibdata1 under C:/xampp/mysql/data/ and i found it.
 Please if there is any solution i can do because i have like 10 tables i cant just re-create them, it's to much work...
The error is

table does not exist in engine

[image]

Comment: Here is the screenshot   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY3hF.png

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: If your data's important, **make regular backups**. If you've lost data, maybe back up the remaining data. MySQL stores table data in potentially many different files depending on your configuration.